# Python Selenium - Google displays captcha on search

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get hands on with selenium and webdriver with python.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "119.82.253.95:61853"
url = 'http://google.co.in/search?q=book+flights'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

When I access normally without a proxy everything works fine. But when I try to access using proxy it shows captcha with message "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer". How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Google has decided that traffic from the proxy IP has acted in an unusual way and they want to be sure you're not a bot (which your Selenium code kind of is).

It's possible also to detect whether someone is using Selenium specifically but I doubt Google is doing that, especially if you were using Selenium when not on the proxy. If you didn't use Selenium when not on the proxy, then you should compare through Fiddler what you're sending to Google.

Maybe you could try with a proxy sitting on a different IP.

Do you have access to the machine on the proxy IP? You could try running the code from there directly and not using a proxy, then see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Chrom looks at the local LAN settings because this google check you, Are you human or bot.
You can do that :

```
 PROXY = "119.82.253.95:61853"
  webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "proxyAutoconfigUrl": '',
        "noProxy": '',
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
        "autodetect": False

    }
    with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webDriver\chromedriver.exe") as driver:
        driver.get('http://www.google.com')
        # enter your code
```

I test this and its work, If you need more information you can take help at [githup](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2463)